# How to get Sendgrid Webhook live events in .NET 4.8?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to get live SendGrid webhook events in .NET 4.8, how to do that in C# .NET?

```
[HttpPost("Sendgridwh")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Sendgridwh([FromBody] object[] eventList)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventList);

    var parser = new WebhookParser();
    var events = parser.ParseEvents(json);

    // this is my custom method
    await IEmailTrackingService.EmailActivityFromWebhook(events);

    return new OkResult();
}
```

I have use **EmailActivityFromWebhook(events)** method in my controller & it was declared in my service file which gets/post data on/from SendGrid webhook & now I was blocked at **EmailActivityFromWebhook(events)** method that I don't know how exactly do code to post/get data on/from webhook in this **EmailActivityFromWebhook(events)** method. I want to get live events like Engagement events & Delivery events of last sent mail. Does anyone know how this could be done? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're doing inside of `EmailActivityFromWebhook`, so I can't help you with that.
Here's a sample to receive the SendGrid events, and then use JSON.NET to parse the JSON Array, and extract the values you want.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SendGridEvents.Controllers
{
    public class SendGridController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost()]
        [Route("SendGridEvent")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Event()
        {
            JArray events;
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                events = serializer.Deserialize<JArray>(jsonReader);
            }

            foreach (JObject sendGridEvent in events){
                var eventId = sendGridEvent["sg_event_id"];
                var eventType = sendGridEvent["event"];
                var email = sendGridEvent["email"];
                Debug.WriteLine($"Event ID: {eventId}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Event Type: {eventType}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Email: {email}");
            }

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use strongly-typed objects and have MVC bind the JSON to objects, but it gets a little complicated because depending on the `event` JSON property, there may be more or less properties in the JSON object. (See [Event Webhook docs for different event type JSON](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event))

By using JSON.NET with a `JArray` and then inspecting individual `JObject`'s, you can extract the `event` property and use different logic as necessary by your requirements.

If this doesn't help, let us know what you're looking for.

---

**Update 1: OP clarified they use ASP.NET Core**

Here's the ASP.NET Core equivalent using `System.Text.Json` instead of JSON.NET:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SendGridEvents.Controllers;

public class SendGridController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<SendGridController> logger;

    public SendGridController(ILogger<SendGridController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    
    [HttpPost("SendGridEvent")]
    public  async Task<ActionResult> Event()
    {
        using (JsonDocument document = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(Request.Body))
        {
            foreach (JsonElement sendGridEvent in document.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
            {
                var eventId = sendGridEvent.GetProperty("sg_event_id").GetString();
                var eventType = sendGridEvent.GetProperty("event").GetString();
                var email = sendGridEvent.GetProperty("email").GetString();
                logger.LogInformation("Event ID: {EventId}", eventId);
                logger.LogInformation("Event Type: {EventType}", eventType);
                logger.LogInformation("Email: {Email}", email);
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

With ASP.NET Core you can even use parameter binding which makes this simpler:

```cs
[HttpPost("SendGridEvent")]
public  ActionResult Event([FromBody]JsonDocument document)
{
    foreach (JsonElement sendGridEvent in document.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
    {
        var eventId = sendGridEvent.GetProperty("sg_event_id").GetString();
        var eventType = sendGridEvent.GetProperty("event").GetString();
        var email = sendGridEvent.GetProperty("email").GetString();
        logger.LogInformation("Event ID: {EventId}", eventId);
        logger.LogInformation("Event Type: {EventType}", eventType);
        logger.LogInformation("Email: {Email}", email);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

You can still bind this JSON to an array or list of strongly-typed objects if you'd like, but with the same caveats as mentioned before.

- [Docs for not binding to strongly-typed object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-jsondocument)
- [Docs for binding to strongly-typed objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: I've tried your solution but I'm using ASPNetCore MVC so which gives me error for new StreamReader(Request.InputStream) & I'm not doing any code in EmailActivityFromWebhook() because I've blocked there that exactly how to do this. So this is simply a function inside my service file but I haven't write any code in it.

Comment: I want to get live events from sendgrid using webhook, i.e status of sent mail, tracking of open & click counts, getting sendgrid messageID, Engagement & delivery events etc. But I don't understand how to do it programatically. I've test live events on webhook.site   i.e using public URL, but now I want to implement this in my controller. Does any solution for this?

Comment: I did not know you were using ASP.NET Core MVC, as your question stated you were using .NET 4.8 which can only run ASP.NET MVC. Let me add an ASP.NET Core MVC sample as well.

Comment: ASP.NET Core sample added 

Comment: I get empty, null request body here & I haven't any idea to how to call this post call of API.

Comment: @DM How are you configuring your events webhook in SendGrid? I'll try to match your configuration to see if it works for me

Comment: 1) I called this api call through service in my component.ts file in angular 7, like this  EX:-  `if (mail != null)                                                                                                                        {
      this.emailsService.emailActivityFromWebhook(mail).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log("successfull");
      })       }`

Comment: 2) This is my method in service.ts file like=>                       
 `emailActivityFromWebhook(events) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiServiceUrl}/api/EmailTracking/SendGridEvent`, events);
  }`

Comment: 3) Here the **"mail"** in first example is the object which having keys like to, from, subject, dateTimeSent, ...etc. So I simply pass this **"mail"** object to that 'post' api call which I posted in the question.    4) I have an UI in which I clicked on button then this api call hits & pass this object to api call. I can configure simply like this nothing more complex & extra. 5) I used Angular 7 for frontend & ASP DotNet Core MVC      V 2.2 for backend.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused. It may be better to share the code using GitHub or a Gist :)
If I understand correctly, you are trying to send an HTTP request from your front end, to your ASP.NET backend.
The thing about webhooks is that you don't call them yourself, an external service calls them. So in this case, SendGrid will send the HTTP requests to your webhook for the events that you're subscribing to.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm cleared about webhook & external services.  So is we use this webhooks for local & test it  for our local url?

Comment: Since your locally running project isn't publicly reachable, Twilio also can't send the http requests. That's why developers usually use a tool like ngrok to tunnel their local service publicly. Grab the https-URL from your ASP.NET project and in a shell, run `ngrok http [your_https_url]`. ngrok will create a public tunnel for your. Grab the https Forwarding URL from the command output and combine it with your MVC route. Then use that public URL to configure your Webhook URL in the SendGrid app.

Comment: Thanks, for this solution to use ngrok tunnel service

Comment: @DM My pleasure! Don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your question.